# How to hide the email address of users in Alfresco?

Tags: privacy, open-source, alfresco

Alfresco is an open source [Enterprise Content Management](http://www.alfresco.com/community/) platform, users are registered with a username and often enter an email address.

By default the email address is visible, for instance at `https://<server>/share/page/user/<user>/profile` (*User Profile Page*) in the "*Contact Information*" section.

**QUESTION:** How to make this information invisible to users?
Preferably without modifying the source code, just by configuration.

*(Reason: depending on the deployment scenario, showing email addresses can be seen as a privacy violation)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I don't think this question should be in superuser section. Second, you have two choices. Either you delete a row in the original web script (not recommended), or you override the widget instantiation with a custom one without the email in the properties array exposed.
Either way, you'd have to look into the web script located here:

`/share/page/script/org/alfresco/components/profile/userprofile.get`

you can find it from here:

`/share/service/index`

you'll find the `email` property in the template file. just comment every reference to it and you should be fine.